# Integrate physical equation / boundaries in neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

I am modelling a reactor operation with neural network which has 4 inputs (X1, X2, X3 and X3) and 3 outputs (Y1, Y2 and Y3) using PYTHON - scilearn. The predicted outputs should als respect a mass balance which can be represented by an equation represented by Y1+Y2+Y3-massflow in = 0. How can this equation or restriction be integrated in neural network? Is this possible?

My dataset is already cleaned by removing the samples where the mass balance is not honored.

```
Code
train_x = ...
train_y = ...
test_x = ...
test_y = ...

processed_data = data[["Y1.PV", "Y2.PV", "Y3.PV", "X1.PV", "X2.PV", "X3.PV", "X4.PV"]]
train, test = train_test_split(processed_data, test_size=.25, random_state=np.random.RandomState(1))

train_x = train.drop(["Y1.PV", "Y2.PV", "Y3.PV"], axis=1)
train_y = train.drop(["Y1.PV", "Y2.PV", "Y3.PV"], axis=1)

test_x = test.drop([""Y1.PV", "Y2.PV", "Y3.PV"], axis=1)
test_y = test.drop(["Y1.PV", "Y2.PV", "Y3.PV"], axis=1)

### TUNED MODEL

best_iter = 2000
best_hidden_layer = 200

neural_net = MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', hidden_layer_sizes=best_hidden_layer, random_state=1, max_iter=best_iter)
scaler = StandardScaler()
model = make_pipeline(scaler, neural_net)
model.fit(train_x, train_y)

### END SOLUTION

predict_y_train = model.predict(train_x)
predict_y = model.predict(test_x)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10,4))
axs[0].scatter(train_y, predict_y_train)
axs[0].set_title("Train data")
axs[1].scatter(test_y, predict_y)
axs[1].set_title("Test data")

print("MSE train:", mean_squared_error(train_y, predict_y_train))
print("MSE test:", mean_squared_error(test_y, predict_y))
```

Comment: scikitlearn is not a right tool for any custom problems. It is a library with off the shelf basic methods, but does not provide any real tools to do anything even remotely non standard

Comment: What tool do you recommend to use?

Comment: any actual NN library, tf, keras, pytorch, jax

Comment: Is `massflow` a constant scalar or does it vary for each sample?

Comment: The massflow varies each sample.

Comment: Thanks for the code - I will definitely try it out

Comment: The situation is actually quite different if `massflow` is not fixed but varies with each sample - see the new edit to my answer.

Comment: Super, thanks! I will test the code.

Comment: It has been another week. If my suggestions pointed you the right way by now, you might want to consider marking my answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes, for sure !

Answer (score 0):

A simple variable reduction approach could be to reduce the network's outputs to `Y1` and `Y2` and to replace any occurence of `Y3` (e.g. in the loss function) with `massflow-Y1-Y2`.

---

**EDIT** It seems that `scikit-learn` only provides very specialized methods for training neural networks and is not suited for your problem. If, instead, you want to try `tensorflow`, then here is a minimum working example to get you started:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def constraint_mse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    massflow = 2
    y3 = tf.expand_dims(massflow-y_pred[:,0]-y_pred[:,1],axis=1)
    y_pred = tf.concat((y_pred,y3),axis=1)
    return tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)

def main():
    massflow = 2

    # generate random training data
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    X   = rng.random((100,4))
    y   = rng.random((100,2))
    y   = np.concatenate((y,massflow-y[:,[0]]-y[:,[1]]), axis=1)

    # define model
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.Input(shape=4),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="linear")
    ])
    model.compile(
        loss = constraint_mse_loss,
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    )

    # run training
    model.fit(X,y,
              batch_size = 16,
              epochs = 10,
              shuffle = True,
              validation_split = 0.2
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I used randomly generated data here and set `massflow=2` at random, replace this with your actual data. The proposed model architecture as well as all hyperparameters are meant as examples. The main point here lies in the custom loss function `constraint_mse_loss` that implements a mean squared error loss together with the required massflow constraint. Once trained, the model only outputs `Y1` and `Y2`, while `Y3` can be retrieved as `Y3=massflow-Y1-Y2`.

---

**FURTHER EDIT** Things are quite different if `massflow`, as you now clarified, actually varies with each sample. That makes the `massflow` itself an input to the model. The following minimum working example covers this situation better:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def main():
    # generate random training data
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    X   = rng.random((100,4))
    massflow = rng.random((100,1))
    X   = {'X': X, 'massflow': massflow}
    y   = rng.random((100,2))
    y   = np.concatenate((y,massflow-y[:,[0]]-y[:,[1]]), axis=1)

    inputs = {
        'X':        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,), name='X',        dtype=tf.float32),
        'massflow': tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='massflow', dtype=tf.float32)
    }
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100)(inputs['X'])
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation="relu")(x)
    y1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
    y2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
    y3 = tf.keras.layers.Add()([y1,y2])
    y3 = tf.keras.layers.Subtract()([inputs['massflow'],y3])
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(name='y')([y1,y2,y3])

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs)
    model.compile(
        loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    )

    # run training
    model.fit(X,y,
        batch_size = 16,
        epochs = 10,
        shuffle = True,
        validation_split = 0.2
    )

    X = {'X': rng.random((1,4)), 'massflow': rng.random((1,1))}
    y = model.predict(X)
    print(f"Massflow {X['massflow'][0,0]:.4f} should be equal to sum of outputs {y.sum():.4f}.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here, enforcing your massflow constraint is part of the model. Its outputs now are `Y1`, `Y2` and `Y3` where the relation `Y3=massflow-Y1-Y2` is enforced. As a nice side-effect, we now can work with the built-in MSE loss and don't need to use a custom loss implementation. Again, the proposed model architecture and all hyperparameters are meant as examples and must still be adjusted to your data.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach. You cannot easily constrain the learned weights of the model to respect any particular relationship. You must instead use the outputs of the model to parameterize a set of outputs where the relationship can be explicitly and exactly modeled.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply - How can this be implemented with scilearn / python? This is not clear to me.

Comment: Please provide us with your implementation so far that you outlined in your question. Then we can help you with the required adjustments.

Comment: How can the loss function be adjusted? Is this possible with Scilearn (or have to switch to Tensorflow or Keras)?

Comment: The code (implementation of neural net) is:best_iter = 2000
best_hidden_layer = 200

neural_net = MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', hidden_layer_sizes=best_hidden_layer, random_state=1, max_iter=best_iter)
scaler = StandardScaler()
model = make_pipeline(scaler, neural_net)
model.fit(train_x, train_y)

### END SOLUTION

predict_y_train = model.predict(train_x)
predict_y = model.predict(test_x)

Comment: Please don't squish your code in the comment section, but add it to your original question.

Comment: Ok - thanks. I added the code to my original request